# iam getting error like ORA-27125: unable to create shared memory segment

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, hp-ux, itanium

When I am trying to create db instances, I am getting errors like below:

> SQL> ORA-27125: unable to create shared memory segment HPUX-ia64
>   Error: 12: Not enough space

My system physical memory has 15.68 GB and my

```
shmmax value is = 1640MB
sga_max_size = 3540MB
sga_target = 3540MB
```

and in opt/oracle has more than 10gb. I have tried modifying `sga` value but still i am only getting error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a system configuration problem. Oracle should have written some diagnostic information in the Alert Log. You need to look at that and see whether that helps.

Comment: In alert log there is no information same error is printed there also....

Comment: Are there any trace files?

Comment: No.Its like a /../alert$ORACLE_SID.log.Its also contain same error.